# setinterval() looping at random times

Tags: javascript, random, setinterval

I am trying to use the `setinterval()` function to loop once and take a random amount of time to call and run a function called `main()`.

Updated code...

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Links</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
    <a href="settings.html">
      <button>click here</button>
    </a><br>
    <a href="https://github.com/shanegibney/link-two-pages">
      <button>Back to repository</button><br>
      <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>

<script>
// Set timeout function
const timeout = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

// Random cycle async function
const randCycle = async (mc, ms) => {
  // Run loop for max cycles
  for(let i = 1; i <= mc; i++) {
    // Generate random from ms limit
    const rms = Math.floor(Math.random() * ms);
    // Await for timeout
    await timeout(rms);
    // Log timeout ms
    console.log(`[${i}] ping in ${rms} ms`);
  }
}

// Run 9 random cycles with 4000 ms limit
randCycle(9, 4000);
  </script>
</html>
```

What is wrong with this code? It should log out LOG a random amount of times either at 1,2,3 or 4 second intervals.

Is this the best way to do it or should I use `each()`?

Comment: I think you need to call [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval) to destroy the old timer.

Comment: How does the current behaviour differ from the expected one?

Comment: It's actually not working or outputting anything. But thanks everyone for looking at this and I will try clearinterval().

Comment: Maybe use setTimeout instead of setInterval since it's being called over and over. Also, why call draw() twice? Just once would do the trick. All these combined are making this function grow expotentially

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also as an option you can utilize `for` loop with `async/await` feature, instead of regular `setInterval` function:

```js
// Set timeout function
const timeout = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

// Random cycle async function
const randCycle = async (mc, ms) => {
  // Run loop for max cycles
  for(let i = 1; i <= mc; i++) {
    // Generate random from ms limit
    const rms = Math.floor(Math.random() * ms);
    // Await for timeout
    await timeout(rms);
    // Log timeout ms
    console.log(`[${i}] ping in ${rms} ms`);
  }
}

// Run 9 random cycles with 4000 ms limit
randCycle(9, 4000);
```

Comment: I see your using the for loop and promises. Your code is running on this site but I can't get it to run on my own computer likr it is above.

Comment: @ShaneG how you want to run it in your case - log to console or show something on page? Because if I run HTML from your updated question, I do get console output